# Yup Validation With Multiple Condition based on other field value

Tags: javascript, reactjs, yup

I have to validate the 'description' field when 'gender' field value is others or female but when it is male no validation required for the 'description' field.

First I want to show this code and this is valid and working:

```js
description: Yup.string().when(['gender'], {
 is: (gender) => gender=== 'others',
 then: Yup.string().required('Description is Required')
})
```

But Now I have to use multiple conditions like this:

```js
description: Yup.string().when(['gender'], {
 is: (gender) => gender=== 'others' || 'female' ,
 then: Yup.string().required('Description is Required')
})
```

But It's not working. Please Give me a solution. Thanks in advance...

Comment: What values are you trying to validate? Are there any errors? _"But It's not working"_ please give more information on what is not working.

Comment: You cannot do `gender=== 'others' || 'female'` because `Boolean || "female"` is not what you expect I think. Instead: use `/^others|female$/.test(gender)`

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan I need Validate description field when gender field value female or others, But when gender field value male then no validate apply for description field

Comment: @evolutionxbox I need to validate description when gender field value is others or female otherwise no validation require but when I am try to use 2nd code snippet is only check first value('others'), or operator condition not working. I think yup didn't accept this but how can I solve this issue

Answer (score 4):

Equality operation is evaluated first.

```
is: (gender) => gender === 'others' || 'female' ,   // Not good
```

becomes:

```
is: (gender) => (Boolean) || 'female',
```

where if `<Boolean>` is `true` you'll get `true` as result,
and if `<Boolean>` is `false` you'll get `"female"` as result.

**SOLUTION:**
Instead, use `/^(others|female)$/.test(gender)`
or `['others','female'].includes(gender)` as suggested by @evolution

```
is: (gender) => /^(others|female)$/.test(gender) ,
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/test

or if you want to make it long and explicit:

```
is: (gender) => gender === "others" || gender === "female" ,
```

Comment: Another solution could also be `['others','female'].includes(gender)`

Comment: @evolutionxbox yep. Added. Thx

Comment: Thanks @RokoC.Buljan

Answer (score 0):

```
// in the context variable you get the full object and retrieve your value from here

.test('DOB', "Single condition error here", (value, context) => {
      const { parent } = context;
      // formatted date passing the formatted the date
      const formatedDate = moment(value).format('YYYY/MM/DD');
      // calculateBirthYear is a custom function for getting age calculated

      const selectedAge = calculateBirthYear(formatedDate);
      if (parent?.role == "3") {
        if (selectedAge >= 21 && selectedAge <= 45)
          return true
      } else if (parent?.role == "4") {
        if (selectedAge >= 18 && selectedAge <= 40)
          return true
      } else if (parent?.role == "5") {
        console.log("LINE NO 138 ", parent.role, selectedAge);
        if (selectedAge >= 18 && selectedAge <= 40)
          return true
      }
      return ctx.createError({ message: parent?.role == "3" ? Strings.sm_register.Surrogate_Mother_error : parent?.role == "4" ? Strings.sm_register.Egg_Donar_error : Strings.sm_register.Sperm_Donar_error });
    }),
```